# Add-SPSolution Error An object in the SharePoint administrative framework, "SPSolutionLanguagePack Name=0

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, solution-package

When I tried to add my wsp solution I am getting the error,

> An object in the SharePoint administrative framework,
>   "SPSolutionLanguagePack Name=0 Parent=SPSolution
>   Name=myeventreceiver.wsp", depends on other objects which do not
>   exist.Ensure that all of the objects dependencies are created and
>   retry this operation.myeventreceiver.wsp:

My environment is having 1 WFE, 1 App Server and 1 DB Server with SP 2013 installed.

This is happening in my staging environment  only, not in my dev or test environment.

I tried restarting the timer service but in vain.I did the **IISReset** also which did not help either.  The only option left is clearing the SPconfig  cache from the ProgramData folder. But I am stuck at doing the clearing the cache.
Should I clear the cache which will result into solving my issue?
I got the script from this link:
 http://blogs.technet.com/b/sp/archive/2013/05/29/clear-sharepoint-config-cache-with-powershell.aspx

```
  Add-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –erroraction 
      SilentlyContinue
        Stop-Service SPTimerV4
        $folders = Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config 
      foreach ($folder in $folders)
       {
      $items = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName -Recurse
      foreach ($item in $items)
        {
           if ($item.Name.ToLower() -eq "cache.ini")
            {
                $cachefolder = $folder.FullName
            }
          }
        }
       $cachefolderitems = Get-ChildItem $cachefolder -Recurse
       foreach ($cachefolderitem in $cachefolderitems)
        {
         if ($cachefolderitem -like "*.xml")
            {
               $cachefolderitem.Delete()
            } }
         $a = Get-Content  $cachefolder\cache.ini
         $a  = 1
         Set-Content $a -Path $cachefolder\cache.ini
          read-host "Do this on all your SharePoint Servers - and THEN press  
           ENTER" 
        start-Service SPTimerV4
```

Comment: Did you try to restart the SharePoint Timer and Admin services on both App and WFE server?

Comment: I restarted the SP Timer Service and Recycling of Application Pool on the App Server and WFE but not the Admin Service.

Comment: try with admin services as well, dont recycle, stop and start it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think This is especially the case if you have just done a retract/uninstall and you try to add straight away. If you try again in a few seconds it will work. Basically this is because when you delete a wsp from solution management and then immediately run this stsadm command, there will still be clean up operations going on in the background. So just leave a slight delay between uninstall of solution packages and re-deploys. Tell me if it is correct.

### If this does not work the you can try below method

We can deploy any components using solution package (WSP). The below steps ensures that Config refresh timer service occurs.

1. Stop the Windows SharePoint Timer Service
2. Open C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\<> folder
3. Take backup of Cache.ini file
4. Delete all the XML files in the GUID folder
5. Open the Cache.ini file in edit mode and delete the contents of it.
6. Type 1.Save and close the file.
7. Start the Windows SharePoint Timer Service.
   Thanks

Comment: Thanks ,I already seen this solution,but my worry is Is there any negative impact if I clear this cache.Also should I do  this for my WFE and App Server ?

Comment: no there is no negative impact.

Comment: The above method always works for me and i can say that its one of the best solution i can think of

Comment: thanks Manish, clearing SPConfig Cache worked.My wsp got installed  after running the script.I am marking your reply as answer though I took the script from the mentioned link.

Comment: Answer here saved me.  I just needed to wait in between retract/removal and adding it again.  Erggh SharePoint can be so annoying with wrong errors!